# Authorize.net test account login on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, authorize.net

I am trying to login to my Authorize.net test account on the iOS Simulator. Upon opening Safari on the simulator I go to the https://test.authorize.net/ website and enter my login ID and password. However it always gives me "The Login ID or password entered is invalid. Please try again.". I have re-checked my loginID and password loads of times to no avail. When I do the same thing on Safari on my Mac it works.

I need this to work since I re-direct the user to the mentioned website during the first time login to authenticate the device. I am unable to login using the mobile safari on simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently the simulator safari settings had cookies turned off. Once I turned the Cookies on the login worked.